# Gwan stops working every night

Tags: g-wan

I have a arch 64bit VPS on digitalocean. I installed gwan and run it in deamon mode. It stopped running every midnight.

Here is the log file

```
[Wed Apr 24 06:10:28 2013 GMT] memory footprint: 3.78 MiB
[Thu, 25 Apr 2013 00:00:19 GMT] * child abort(8) coredump
[Thu, 25 Apr 2013 00:00:19 GMT] * child abort(8) coredump
[Thu, 25 Apr 2013 00:00:19 GMT] * child abort(8) coredump
[Thu, 25 Apr 2013 00:00:19 GMT] * child died 3 times within 3 seconds
[Thu Apr 25 12:39:39 2013 GMT] memory footprint: 3.77 MiB.
[Thu Apr 25 12:39:56 2013 GMT] loaded maintenance script/opt/gwan_linux64-bit/0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0/csp/crash.c 43.14 KiB   MD5:820cf6b4-2152b838-08a13fcb-5f0dc4be
[Fri, 26 Apr 2013 00:00:10 GMT] * child abort(8) coredump
[Fri, 26 Apr 2013 00:00:10 GMT] * child abort(8) coredump
[Fri, 26 Apr 2013 00:00:10 GMT] * child abort(8) coredump
[Fri, 26 Apr 2013 00:00:10 GMT] * child died 3 times within 3 seconds
```

Comment: Yes something looks wrong with latest version ... wait & see next version

Comment: Maybe a web page with all versions available to download will be a nice things to have ... Gil, Pierre, it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not happen on all platforms and so far all the user reports we received used [hypervisors](http://gwan.ch/faq#hypervisors) which alter the CPU and OS behavior in erratic and undocumented ways (not to cite the additional bugs they inject into the system).

---

UPDATE

That new problem for 4-years old code that worked fine so far is a platform issue, for which we have found a workaround, to be published with the next release in a few weeks.

Comment: It occurs for me on dedicated server running archlinux, but it looks to work fine on a centos dedicated one.

Comment: Any news about this bug ? It still happening for me on a debian 7 dedicated server ...