# Where is the latest version of G-WAN?

Tags: version, g-wan

in this question [g-wan - reproducing the performance claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784753/g-wan-reproducing-the-performance-claims) I saw that gwan is up to **v4.11.7** while gwan.ch/com only provides **v4.3.17** (March 17, 2013), am I missing something ?

Comment: New release is coming soon after they finalize/test everything making sure it's fit for release. I've been shown a recent release and it fixes a lot of issues of the past, and as always, performs faster than anything else. I would expect it to be out mid-month or by the end of this month at the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are g-wan support plan subscriber, you could be invited to participate in the testing of new versions before their oficial release.

Comment: In fact, when we receive useful feedback from unregistered users and have a release that can help them then we email them the latest development release along with an explanation of what is going to be shipped in the next public release. When we don't have a fix for a reported problem then we fix the glitch and email the release to the user who reported the issue, as a reward for the positive feedback.

Comment: I confirm, I'm not a GWAN support plan subscriber (not yet), but I help GWAN team by describing bugs found ... I'm running 4.11.11 right now :)

Comment: since it's not published yet, is the latest 4.11.11 fixed this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229617/gwan-stops-working-every-night/16272464#comment26666998_16272464 ?

Comment: @csw, It don't stop now on my digitalocean debian7 dropplet !

Comment: @solisoft , the release cycle is too slow. wonder why not published a beta version..

Comment: @csw I agree, missing communication about this project ... Which is an amazing one.

Comment: I'm running 4.11.19 and I can confirm all features are working as expected, even in VM environments. There is no random stopping, unless you run buggy code that causes seg faults or other issues.

Answer (score 0):

G-WAN v5.1 is expected to be released later this month (Feb 2014)!
http://gwan.com/en_timeline.html

Comment: Why February??? This month must refer to the current month, which is JANUARY 2014!

Comment: quoted from official site:------  

G-WAN v5 was expected to be released in January...

...but we are dealing with the unexpected blocking of our outgoing emails – despite the fact that our domain names and corporate RIPE IP block are clear on 50+ mail blacklists.

We do not do any mailing campaign nor we even published newsletters so far, but that does not prevent some major industry players from blocking our mails. Let's hope that they will finally respond to our delisting requests.

Comment: i am waiting for direct download from the official site. Would it be ok if update the official download page first, instead of waiting for the recovery of the outgoing emails from g-wan?

Comment: I second this opinion.